# How to properly return generic array in Java generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I have below generic method that returns a generic array:

```
public static <T> T[] genericMethod1(List<T> input) {
    T[] res = (T[]) new Object[input.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (T t : input) {
        res[i] = t;
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}

public static <T> T genericMethod2(List<T> input) {
    return input.get(0);
}
```

But later when I try to get the result array with:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.addFirst(1);
list.addFirst(1);

Integer[] i = (Integer[]) genericMethod1(list);  // 1) Runtime error
Integer j = genericMethod2(list);        // 2) works
```

For case 1, I always get error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

Anybody can explain why and how to return the generic array properly? Thanks.

> Below is my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong.
>
> As Tim mentioned, type erasure happened at compile time, so in bytecode, each T object is just type Object, meanwhile, compiler will add type cast from Object to T "properly".
>
> Say T is an Integer, where T is declared, it's Object. For where it's referred, it's type cast (implicitly) to T.
>
> EXCEPT that if T[] array is declared, it's Object[], and where the array is referred, it stays Object[]. No implicit cast to T[] happens.

Comment: Generics does not retain type at run-time.

Comment: To summarize here, type erasure removes the type, so if you want to return a generic array of a specific type, you will need to pass in that type.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The explanation for what you are seeing is due to something called *type erasure*.  Here is what your `genericMethod()` will look like *after* the compiler performs type erasure:

```
public static Object[] genericMethod(List input) {
    Object[] res = new Object[input.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (Object t : input) {
        res[i] = t;
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

In other words, this method will return an array of type `Object`.  There is no way to cast an `Object[]` to an `Integer[]` because they are not the same type.  If you want your method to be able to dynamically return the type you want, then you can use `Array.newInstance()`.  This will require also passing in the type of the array you want as an input parameter:

```
public static <T> T[] genericMethod(Class<T> clazz, List<T> input) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, input.size());

    int i = 0;
    for (T t : input) {
        res[i] = t;
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now your code snippet will run without error:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();    
Integer[] i = genericMethod(Integer.class, list);
```

**Update:**

Your second method, `genericMethod2()`, will look like this after type erasure:

```
public static Object genericMethod2(List input) {
    return input.get(0);
}
```

It will return the first element of the input list, cast to `Object`.  Here is your usage of that method:

```
Integer j = genericMethod2(list);
```

The compiler will try to cast the output from `genericMethod2()` to `Integer`:

```
Integer j = (Integer)genericMethod2(list);
```

This cast is legal, because every `Integer` is also an `Object`, and furthermore it succeeds here because you passed in a collection of `Integer`.  This second method is not the same scenario as the first one you highlighted for us.

Comment: @Tom Biegeleisen Thanks for your comment. But I guess another reason is that Type Erasure and implicit type cast is not suitable for array type. Please see my modified question.

Comment: OK I will update my answer.  By the way, Tom Biegeleisen is my brother.

Comment: Tim and Tom. Sounds like a movie:-)

Answer (score 4):

When calling the method, `genericMethod` you are assuming that it returns array of integers, which is NOT correct. It actually returns array of type Object at runtime.

```
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    input.add(1);
    Object[] output = genericMethod(input);
    for(Object obj : output){
        System.out.println("Value= "+ (Integer)obj);
    }
```

So we need to cast the individual content of the array.

> One general guidline is that we shouldn't mix ARRAY and GENERICS in Java.

**Update:**

Reference from [Effective Java](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=don't%20mix%20array%20and%20generics%20in%20java&source=bl&ots=yZHiMip1T0&sig=4bCiNPsSHMh881XZdyRyVWp0tNI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl-aqT37zKAhWIc44KHSjdDsYQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=don't%20mix%20array%20and%20generics%20in%20java&f=false):

> In Summary, arrays and generics have very different type rules. Arrays are covariant and reified; generics are invariant and erased. As a consequcne, arrays provide runtime type safety but not compile-time type safety and vice versa for generics. Generally speaking, arrays and generics don’t mix well. If you find yourself mixing them and getting compile-time error or warnings, your first impulse should be to replace the arrays with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do it like in `java.util.ArrayList.toArray(T[])`.
You pass the type of Array to that Method, if it's big enough it will be reused, otherwise an new Array is generated.

Example:

```
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    intList.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    intList.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
    intList.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
    Integer[] array = intList.toArray(new Integer[] {});
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));//Will Print [1, 2, 3]
```

Implementation of `ArrayList.toArray(T[])` see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 0):

After Java 8 was released, you can leverage constructor references to return a generic array. While there are more straightforward options to convert List to Integer[], I am explaining the concept here **with kinda minimal changes to your code**:

- I am not touching your genericMethod2() implementation
- For `genericMethod1`, let's add a second parameter that will accept a constructor reference. Then you can call the apply() function on the constructor reference to create a generic array.

  - you pass `Integer[]::new` to this new parameter. `Integer[]::new` is treated as `(int x) => new Integer[x]`
  - fi.apply(input.size()) calls `(int x) => new Integer[x]` with argument `input.size()`. The result is a `Integer[]`. This is why the `IntFunction` parameter has generic type `T[]`

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class RetGenericArr {
  public static <T> T[] genericMethod1(List<T> input, IntFunction<T[]> fi) {
    T[] res = fi.apply(input.size());

    int i = 0;
    for (T t : input) {
      res[i] = t;
      i++;
    }
    return res;
  }

  public static <T> T genericMethod2(List<T> input) {
    return input.get(0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.addFirst(1);
    list.addFirst(2);

    // umm I am uncomfortable about the variable naming below:
    Integer[] i = genericMethod1(list, Integer[]::new); // Now no error/warning. Note that I am not casting now
    for (int e: i) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    Integer j = genericMethod2(list);
  }
}
```