# How to write a java function to return array of dynamic type?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a situation where i want to get array of an object of whatever the type the object is.

below is what i tried:

code to call the function:

```
wsDeployedExaminersResponseVO.setDeployedExaminers((DeployedExaminersVO[]) returnArrayForType(wsDeployedExaminersVO));
```

code for function:

```
 public static Object[] returnArrayForType(Object type) throws Exception {
   Object[] objects={type};
   return objects;
 }
```

But when I run the code I get casting Exception at the point where I am calling the code. The Reason why I am doing this is because I am trying to auto generate java code and I am in a need of a function which will return me array of the parameter type or a one liner code which can fit in the set function dynamically based on the type at runtime.

Comment: Can you add the Exception please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two questions:

1. How many items do you have?
2. Does the object's actual type or super type do you need?

Solution

1, For only 1 instance

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T[] getArray(T value) {
    Object array = Array.newInstance(value.getClass(), 1);
    Array.set(array, 0, value);
    return (T[]) array;
  }
```

2, For multiple objects

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T[] getArray(T... value) {
    return value;
  }
```

3, For explicit type

3.1 For 1 instance

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T[] getArray(Class<T> clz, Object value) {
    Object array = Array.newInstance(clz, 1);
    Array.set(array, 0, value);
    return (T[]) array;
  }
```

3.2 For multiple instances

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T[] getArray(Class<T> clz, Object... values) {
    Object array = Array.newInstance(clz, values.length);
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, clz, 0, values.length);
    return (T[]) array;
  }
```

Comment: But notice that the second way's type is inferred by complier. For example: `getArray("1", 1)` will return `Serializable[]`.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939499/how-to-properly-return-generic-array-in-java-generic-method/34939580#34939580), you can solve it using generics. I hope the following code helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Integer[] a = genericMethod(Integer.class, 5);
    String[] b = genericMethod(String.class, "dddddddddddd");
}

public static <T> T[] genericMethod(Class<T> clazz, T input) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 1);
    res[0] = input;
    return res;
}
```