# collecting Stream results in ClassCastException

Tags: java-stream, classcastexception

I'm experiencing a ClassCastException with the following piece of code.

```
var temp = set.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(Token[]::new);
```

I also tried collecting into a set, but I got the same error.

```
var temp = set.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

set is declared as a Set<Token[]>, but when debugging it says Set<Object[]>.

Edit:

I've narrowed down the issue to the method subsetsWithMinSize. Eventhough I call it with:

```
new Sets<Token>().subsetsWithMinSize(value, x);
```

it seems to return a Set<Object[]>. Can someone tell me why that is and how to fix it?

Here is the method subsetsWithMinSize:

```
public Set<T[]> subsetsWithMinSize(List<T> list, int min) {
    Set<T[]> res = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - min; i++)
        for (int j = 0; list.size() - j >= i + min; j++) {
            List<T> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = i; k < list.size() - j; k++) temp.add(list.get(k));
            res.add((T[]) temp.toArray());
        }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: And what is `set`?

Comment: I just put the full code there.

Comment: Your working one uses `Object[]` and your broken one uses `Token[]` and the error is about trying to cast the former to the latter. Resolving that discrepancy might be a starting point.

Comment: `var temp = set.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(Token[]::new);` works nicely on my Java 17. Which Java version are you on?

Comment: I think I found the issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I am using a generic class to get the powerset. How should I resolve it.

Comment: @Ole V.V I tried 16 and 18 actually, but I guess that's not the issue.

Comment: I am getting a bit confused now and have a hard time understanding how your pieces should fit together. Could you create a [mre], please?

Comment: I still cannot reproduce. I created `Set<Token[]> st` and passed it to `Set<Set<Token[]>> pst = powerSetWithMaxSize(st, 12);`. Then passing `pst` to `reduce()` works nicely.

Comment: A detail, you need to declare the type parameter in the generic method signature: `public <T> Set<Set<T>> powerSetWithMaxSize(Set<T> originalSet, int max)`.

Comment: I've put the method powerSetWithMaxSize in a class called Sets in a different package. I'll put the necessary code there so it's better understandable.

Comment: Does it maybe have to do with the term T[]?

Comment: You could reduce your question to one or a maximum of two code blocks. There is a lot of excessive information.

Comment: Some people asked for the additional information. I'll edit the unnecessary blocks out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

So after you guys helped me to minimise the search scope I found the issue.

When I was using (T[]) to cast it wouldn't work, because after type erasure T would just be cast to an Object. Here's the thread I found the answer on: [How to properly return generic array in Java generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939499/how-to-properly-return-generic-array-in-java-generic-method).

So to finally correct the code I had to change the method a little by using `Array.newInstance()` and put in `Class<T>` to make it work:

```
public Set<T[]> subsetsWithMinSize(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list, int min) {
    Set<T[]> res = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - min; i++)
        for (int j = 0; list.size() - j >= i + min; j++) {
            List<T> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = i; k < list.size() - j; k++)
                temp.add(list.get(k));
            var arr = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, temp.size());
            IntStream.range(0, temp.size()).forEach(k -> arr[k] = temp.get(k));
            res.add(arr);
        }
    return res;
}
```

It uses `Array.newInstance()` to make `T[]` (cast is still necessary for the compiler) and then just copies temp into that array.

Another option would be to use lists instead of arrays, which is the better way.

Reference from [Effective Java](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=don%27t%20mix%20array%20and%20generics%20in%20java&source=bl&ots=yZHiMip1T0&sig=4bCiNPsSHMh881XZdyRyVWp0tNI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl-aqT37zKAhWIc44KHSjdDsYQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=don%27t%20mix%20array%20and%20generics%20in%20java&f=false):

> In Summary, arrays and generics have very different type rules. Arrays are covariant and reified; generics are invariant and erased. As a consequcne, arrays provide runtime type safety but not compile-time type safety and vice versa for generics. Generally speaking, arrays and generics don’t mix well. If you find yourself mixing them and getting compile-time error or warnings, your first impulse should be to replace the arrays with lists.

The issue with that is that, for my use at least, lists use an unnecessarily big amount of space. Combined with the fact that I am making a powerset of the results later everything would just run super slow.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I was going to say the same: Replace `Token[]` with `List<Token>` throughout. And I see now that it will help and simplify.

Comment: If you want it simpler and faster, put `T[] template = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 0);` at the beginning of the method and replace the entire the inner loop body with `res.add(list.subList(i, list.size() - j).toArray(template));` But of course, if you want a really space efficient solution, you’d just add the sublists to a `Set<List<T>>`.

Comment: Yes, thanks guys. I actually prefer Arrays in this case, since the amount of values stored in there are very few. But I really like the idea with the sublists.